# Searching for a date In a partitioned table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning, database-partitioning, datetime2

When doing queries on a partitioned table in SQL Server, does one have to do anything special?

The reason I am asking is because we have a fairly large SQL Server table that is partitioned on a `datetime2(2)' column by day.

Each day is mapped to its own file group with a file in that file group named appropriately such as `Logs_2014-09-15.ndf`.

If I do a query on this table that say, only spans 2 days. I see that in ResourceMonitor that SQL Server is accessing more than 2 of the daily `.ndf` files. (edit, in fact I have noticed that it goes and searched through every single one. even if i Select from a day that falls in partition1 )

From my understanding with partitioned tables, it should only search amongst the appropriate data /partitions that it needs to?

So my questions:

1. Is this the case?
2. does how I compare the `DateTime2` column effect the query?

   For example, I could query like so:

   ```
   select * from LogsTable
   where [date] like '2014-09-15'
   ```

   or I could do:

   ```
   select * from LogsTable
   where [date] = CAST('2014-09-15'AS DATETIME2)
   ```
3. Does the partition function automatically look at the `[time]` element if it is in the query and then send sql to the correct partition?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with this:

```
select * from LogsTable
where Dateadd(D, 0, Datediff(D, 0, [date])) = CAST('2014-09-15'AS DATETIME2)
```